# Как по клику отрисовывать разные данные?

Tags: reactjs

Данные для страницы хранятся внутри объекта. Объект состоит из двух массивов в каждом из которых разные данные. Нужно при клике на кнопку показывать одни данные(из первого массива) при клике на другую кнопку - данные второго массива.
структура примерно такая:`body:{
arr1: [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c: 3}],
arr2: [{a:100}, {b:200}, {c: 300}],
}`

Comment: А что вы уже сделали? Что непонятно?

Comment: нужно написать 3 компонента: 1 контейнер и дву тупых. контейнер хранит ваши данные или знает как их получить и рисует первый тупой компонент (кнопка или что угодно). По клике на кнопку контейнер в цикле из ваших данных рисует второй тупой компонент - которые выши данные превращает во что-то осязаемое